# How to use local .mdf as datasource for VS2013 project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-connection, sql-server-2008

I have an .mdf file that was created in SSMS 2008 R2. I need to use that as the data source for a desktop application project being built in VS 2013 Pro.

When I go through the Data Source Configuration Wizard and select my .mdf file and click Test Connection, I get an error saying the file isn't compatible with the current instance of SQL Server. and to resolve it, I need to upgrade the file with a new data connection (I'm already creating a new data connection) or modifying the existing connection to the file (huh?).

I've spent the last two hours Googling how to do this, but everything I find assumes I know how to do some part of the steps they give.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide "idiot-proof" step-by-step instructions on how to do this!

Comment: Which version of Sql Server do you have installed?

Comment: Check this MSDN link once http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx

Comment: @Steve: SSMS 2008 R2, although I'm quite sure the services aren't  set up to run on my computer.

Comment: @Rahul: According to the note for SS 2008 Express it should be fine (but I'm running the full version of SQL Server).

Comment: @Steve: I have SSMS 2008 R2 installed on my computer, but I've never set up a local server/db instance. None of the .mdf files on my computer have the SSMS icon - just the default, plain white icon. That's another thing I was trying to figure out how to do, but couldn't...